# Clearly not intended for such use, but what are the downsides of using TeamCity to run scheduled application code?

Tags: teamcity

Let's say application `A` has to run at time `T` every night with precision.

In TeamCity, application `A` is scheduled to be run through a build configuration that takes the latest successful build of application `A` as a dependency.

The task performed by `A` is not an integration or a deployment task.

What are the downsides of such a scenario?

Note: I understand there are other tools in the industry whose purpose is to handle scheduling and running application code. This is not an XY Question. I do not want answers giving me alternatives; those answers will be given -1. I'm specifically asking for any reason why TeamCity cannot or should not fill this role.

Comment: Where do you want `A` to run? On the build agent or on some other machine? What is 
 the OS of the build agent/`A` host? Does `A` needs to keep running after the build triggered in TeamCity finishes?

Comment: @tolache Ideally `A` would run on an agent, but not necessarily the same agents that handle actual package builds. I expect doing something like this would require a pool specifically for genuine production-level runs. The OS is unimportant, but without loss of generality, assume Linux. The application code would have a single execution and terminate eventually. The "build configuration" completing would align with the application code finishing.

Comment: Again, the case I'm specifically describing is an arbitrary application `A` that does not produce a build artifact, but rather "does work" of some sort. Are there any downsides to that workflow being done in TeamCity?

Comment: The only downside I see for that scenario is occupying the build agent until `A` exits.